# Does dominated convergence theorem imply convergence in $L^1$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The following is the DCT from Folland real analysis.

[image]

Can I say based on DCT, $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $L^1$?    (i.e. $\int|f_n-f|\rightarrow0$)

**If yes then why? If not, what restriction should be given?**

---

I think the answer is wrong. However the following link confuses me:

[https://math.la.asu.edu/~quigg/teach/courses/473/2009/lectures/11integral.pdf](https://math.la.asu.edu/%7Equigg/teach/courses/473/2009/lectures/11integral.pdf)

(The short proof of Corollary 16 confuses me.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. If $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere then $|f_n-f|\to0$ almost everywhere. And if $|f_n|\le g$ and $f_n\to f$ almost everywhere then $|f|\le g$ almost everywhere, so $|f_n-f|\le 2g$ almost everywhere. So DCT shows that $\int|f_n-f|\to0$.

Comment: Could you say a bit clear for the last sentence?

Comment: Apply dominated convergence to the sequence of functions $\{|f_{n} - f|\}$, which are dominated by the function $2g \in L^{1}$.

Comment: @robjohn Heh, I see you actually posted yours while I was typing mine. Sorry...

Comment: @mlg4080 Let $F_n=|f_n-f|$, $F=0$, $G=2g$. Then $F_n\to F$ almost everywhere, $|F_n|\le G$ and $\int G<\infty$. So DCT says $\int F_n\to\int F$.